# How can I make a multi-item carousel using bootstrap with as little code as possible?

Tags: javascript, angular, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel like this image:

[carousel-multi-ítem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMtHl.jpg)

Estoy trabajando con Angular y Bootstrap, estoy comenzando con ambas frameworks y el código que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```js
<div class="container" id="contenedor-global">


<div *ngIf="inmuebles!=null; else espera">
  <div class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" id="multi_item">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i].id}}_{{inmuebles[i].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>

              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus "></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2" >Precio: {{inmuebles[i].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <h6 class="d-inline-flex ml-2">Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
                </div>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+1].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+1].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+1].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+1].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+2].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+2].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+2].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+3].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+3].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+3].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+3].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+4].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+4].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+4].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+4].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <div class="" *ngIf="inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]!=''; else sino">
                  <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="{{url}}{{inmuebles[i+5].id}}_{{inmuebles[i+5].fotos[0]}}" alt="Card image cap">
              </div>
              <ng-template #sino>
                <img class="card-img-top" id="imgPortada" src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              </ng-template>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><h6>Precio: {{inmuebles[i+5].precio}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline-flex">
                  <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><h6>Ubicacion</h6>
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Ver detalles</button>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert">Apartamento en Valencia</div>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                          <div class="col-6"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width:100%;"> </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Categoría</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Fecha de Publicación</th>
                          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Localización</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="text-center">Apartamentos</td>
                          <td class="text-center">15/02/19</td>
                          <td class="text-center">Valencia</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" (click)="anteriorInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" (click)="siguienteInmueble()" href="#multi_item" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<ng-template #espera>Esperando datos...</ng-template>
</div>
```

I know that the code is too repetitive, I think there must be a way to have a single container and with javascript to generate others but as I say I'm starting recently, I also have a modal that is displayed when you click on each button (see details ) of the items and I also see that the code for this is very repetitive. Finally, what I would like to improve is the Slider code, in the documentation of Bootstrap I see that they only explain to do it with a single image, I also tried to use NGX-BOOTSTRAP and I did not manage to make it work even though I installed all the dependencies as Popper. js, javascript, jquery and Bootstrap. would someone be so kind to lend me a hand? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance. Regards!

Comment: This is where you... extract them and make them into smaller reusable components.

Comment: ok, I could make a component for the modal and call it inside each button, something like that I was thinking, am I right? peromi big problem is the multi-item slider.

Comment: Well, really I see it as 1 main modal component which takes Inputs and it's data changes based on selected item. Your items for your slider will also be a component instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: could you give me a small example friend?